# What is the best way to apply a function to a column in a data frame with sequential changes in the function argument?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using quantmod in R to get price history for the 'QQQ' ETF. I want to calculate the 1:n period rate of change.

I am able to do it using ROC() and can successfully create and name the columns of the xts. I just see it as time intensive - I know there is a better way to do this.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("QQQ")

QQQ <- QQQ$QQQ.Close
View(QQQ)
QQQ <- `colnames<-`(QQQ,"close")

QQQ$ROC1 <- ROC(x = QQQ[,1],n = 1)
QQQ$ROC2 <- ROC(x = QQQ[,1], n = 2)
QQQ$ROC3 <- ROC(x = QQQ[,1], n = 3)
```

I expect that I will have 'n' number of columns 1:n with respective ROC calculations. I understand there will be 'n' number of N/A values per column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = 3
head(cbind(QQQ, setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:n, function(i)
    ROC(x = QQQ[,1], n = i))),
    paste0("ROC", 1:n))))
#           close         ROC1         ROC2        ROC3
#2007-01-03 43.24           NA           NA          NA
#2007-01-04 44.06  0.018786325           NA          NA
#2007-01-05 43.85 -0.004777691  0.014008634          NA
#2007-01-08 43.88  0.000683985 -0.004093706 0.014692619
#2007-01-09 44.10  0.005001079  0.005685064 0.000907373
#2007-01-10 44.62  0.011722429  0.016723508 0.017407493
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mclapply()` from the `parallel` package to use multiple threads to speed the task up:

```r
library(parallel)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("QQQ")

QQQ <- QQQ$QQQ.Close
View(QQQ)
QQQ <- `colnames<-`(QQQ,"close")

mclapply(seq_along(QQQ), function(i) ROC(x = QQQ[, 1], n = i), mc.cores = detectCores())
```